# "Perl : Add an Array Element from one Array into another Array"

Tags: arrays, perl, bioinformatics

I am an absolute newbie to Perl as well as programming in general(less than a month's experience).

I am stumped with a problem which needs to be resolved if I am to solve a bigger issue.

Basically, I have 2 arrays which look like this:

```
@array1 = ('NM_1234' , '1452' , 'NM_345' , '5008' , 'NR_6145' , '256');
@array2 = ('NM_5673' , '2' , 'NM_345' , '5' , 'NR_6145' , '10');
```

`@array1` contains id numbers followed by length. The id number is of nucleotide sequences and length is the length of the sequence.

`@array2` contains id numbers followed by the number of G-Quadruplex structures in each so some sequences contain only 2 such structures while others contain 10 or more.

The basic problem is, I need to add to `@array2`, the "length numbers" in `@array1`(eg 5008, 256) for every matching id number.

So for example as **NM_345** matches in both the arrays, I need to add **5008** to it, so that the final result becomes like **NM_345,5,5008**.

Similarly with **NR_6145** and other such matches ( There are over 20,000 id numbers in `@array2`)

So far, I have been able to write code which can just search for the same id number in both the arrays. Here is the code:

```
#Enter file name
print "Enter file name: ";
$in =<>;
chomp $in;

open(FASTA,"$in") or die;

@data = <FASTA>; #Read in data        
$data = join ('',@data); #Convert to string
@data2 = split('\n',$data); #Explode along newlines

#Enter 2nd file name
print "\n\nEnter 2nd file name: ";
$in2=<>;
chomp $in2;

open(FASTA,"$in2") or die;
@entry =<FASTA>; #Read in data

$entry = join('',@entry); #Convert to string
@entry2 = split('\n',$entry); #Explode along newlines

my %seen;
for  $item (@data2) {
    if($item =~ /([0-9]+)/){
        push @{$seen{$key}}, $item;#WHAT IS THIS DOING? HOW?
    }
}

for my $item (@entry2) {
    if ($item =~ /([0-9]+)/){
        if (exists $seen{$key}) {
            print $item,"\n";
        };        
    }
}
exit;
```

I derived the code which finds the same element from 2 arrays from this solution here, so full credit goes to Chas.Owens: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1064929/1468737.
And of course, I do not quite yet understand this part:

```
push @{$seen{$key}}, $item;#WHAT IS THIS DOING? HOW?
```

It appears to be an array of a hash value or something?

So , now how do I add the length element from @array1 into @array2? I need to use the splice command I think, but how?

My desired output should look like this:

```
NM_345,5,5008 <br>
NM_6145,10,256<br>
etc
```

I also need to save this output into a file which will then later be analyzed to see if there is any correlation between length and G-quadruplex number.

Any help or input will be deeply appreciated.

Thank you for taking the time to go through my problem!

---

EDIT: This edit is to show how the data files look like. They are basically putput files from other programs I wrote.

My first file,named, Transcriptlength.fa, with over 40,000 id numbers going into `@array1` looks like this:

```
NR_037701
3353

NM_198399
2414

NR_026816
601

NR_027917
658

NR_002777
1278
```

My second file,named Quadcount.AllGtranscripts.fa, with over 20,000id numbers going into `@array2`, looks like this:

```
NM_000014   
1

NM_000016   
3

NM_000017   
19

NM_000018   
2

NM_000019   
3

NM_000020   
30

NM_000021   
1

NM_000022   
2

NM_000023   
5

NM_000024   
1

NM_000025   
15

NM_000029   
5
```

Comment: what is the format of the data in each file?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't declare those arrays up top as hashes? That would make the solution Im typing up much easier.

Comment: The first array cannot be easily converted into a hash, I suppose. At least I built my solution assuming exactly that: one can store several lengths for each sequence. )

Comment: Anyway, you want something like `my %data; $data{ 'a_sequence' } = ( $count, $length );` which assigns an array reference to a hash key. Read `perldoc perreftut`

Comment: `($count, $length)` is not a reference, it's a list. `[$count, $length]` should be used instead.

Comment: You must give details of your two data files as it looks like you need help reading those as well as manipulating the arrays.

Comment: @nickisfat The files are output files from another program. One is an output file for computing length of each sequence, the second is an output file for displaying number of G-quadruplexes in a particular sequence. I will try to attach an image which  shows how each file looks like.

Comment: @nickisfat; @Borodin : I tried to upload an image showing how the data files look like, but it appears I am not allowed to post images till 10 reputation points. So, I am editing my post above to show how the files look like.

Comment: @PinkElephantsOnParade : I tried to transfer the data into hash, but it is not taking it in properly. :/ . I used the following line of code to input the contents of the file into a hash: %hash = <FASTA>;

Comment: Is it intentional that sequences in the files you mentioned are named differently: 'NR_*' in the first file, 'NM_*' in the second one? And why their quantities are different: could it be that some sequence is mentioned in the second file (with 20K), but not in the first one (40K)?

Comment: You mentioned that the data files are output of other programs you wrote: it would make your life a lot easier if you updated those programs to save in the format "NM_000014,1(newline)NM_000016,3(newline)" etc

Comment: @raina77ow Hello again! :) There are sequences beginning with NM_* and NR_* in both the files. NM_* refers to mRNA while NR_* refers to any other RNA. I just picked up the first few lines of data from each file and pasted it here. The reason no file with NR_* is visible yet in the second file is because all sequences in the second file are ordered. So NM_* is followed by NR_* sequences.Also, all sequences in second file are present in the first file but not vice versa.

Comment: Very nice, I suppose I'll edit just my answer then - and you'll see how knowing the precise structure of input allows to simplify the code (but, strictly speaking, make our code less flexible). It's a common trade-off actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you are having trouble reading the data files as well as generating the output you want. We cannot help with that part of the problem unless you show us an example of the file data, but here is a solution for producing the output correctly.

It is best if your data is stored in hashes as that allows direct access to the length and structure count for a given sequence ID. Fortunately, arrays laid out as you have described them can easily be converted to hashes by a simple assignment, so this short program does what you want from the arrays you show.

The `grep /\D/, @array2` list in the loop just selects all the sequence IDs from `@array2` by picking only those elements that contain a non-decimal character. I have done it this way in case the order in which the sequences are displayed matters. In your final program you should probably process the data directly from the file instead of reading it into an array so this won't be an issue.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array1 = ( NM_1234 1452   NM_345 5008   NR_6145 256 );
my @array2 = ( NM_5673    2   NM_345    5   NR_6145  10 );

my %lengths = @array1;
my %counts = @array2;

for my $id (grep /\D/, @array2) {
  my $length = $lengths{$id};
  printf "%s,%s,%s\n", $id, $length, $counts{$id} if $length;
}
```

**output**

```
NM_345,5008,5
NR_6145,256,10
```

---

**Update**

Your file data is ideal for setting *paragraph mode* where records are separated by blank lines in the data file. To achieve this you set the *input record separator* variable `$/` to an empty string `""`.

This revised program reads records from the first file, splits them on whitespace (whitespace includes space, tab and newline, amongst others) and builds a hash `%lengths` which relates each sequence ID to its length.

The same is done to the second file, this time checking whether the sequence ID appears in the hash. If so the complete record is output.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fh;
my %lengths;

$/ = "";

open $fh, '<', 'Transcriptlength.fa'
    or die qq(Unable to open "Transcriptlength.fa": $!);

while (<$fh>) {

  my ($id, $length) = split;
  next unless $id;

  $lengths{$id} = $length;
}

open $fh, '<', 'Quadcount.AllGtranscripts.fa'
    or die qq(Unable to open "Quadcount.AllGtranscripts.fa": $!);

while (<$fh>) {

  my ($id, $count) = split;
  next unless $id;

  my $length = $lengths{$id};
  next unless $length;

  print join(',', $id, $count, $length), "\n";
}
```

unfortunately the sample data that you have chosen doesn't contain matching sequence IDs so there is no output from this program when run against that data. Your actual files will be more productive.

Comment: Wow Borodin! Thanks for the wonderful reply and such a delightful code! Indeed you are right , I am having trouble reading the data files. I have edited the original post and I have now included how the 2 data files look like.

Comment: The code you have mentioned works beautifully if my data can be brought into that particular form in an array. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be the case :(  How do I get my data from the 2 files into the hash form?

Comment: I suspected that your files had a sequence ID followed by the corresponding data on the same line. As it turns out your code was a lot closer than I thought. I am updating my answer to read from your files instead of from arrays.

Comment: @Neal: an application like this would benefit a lot from using a database. I understand that may be a big leap if you haven't used SQL or the `DBI` module before, but a simple SQLite database (that doesn't require a database engine to be installed) would solve this easily and leave the data available for further work.

Comment: @ Borodin: Hello sir! First of all, apologies for this late reply as I had been feeling unwell since past 2 days. Okay so your answer sir is so succinct! I mean I am just wondering what a convoluted approach I was using. There is nothing in the book I am referring, "Beginning Perl for Bioinformatics" which could have prepared me to write an algorithm like yours. In fact, I see that both you and raina77ow have used a similar logic. Both programs have something completely new and fascinating for me to learn. As an example, the use of "next" and "unless" is completely new to me!

Comment: Here is the logic I understand sir, please let me know if I understand it correct. While reading in the 1st file in a string format from the $fh file handle, split the records along newline. Go to next record, unless one is still in $id. Now create a hash, in which the the sequence id is linked to its length.

Comment: In the second file, I am a bit unsure about these lines: my $length = $lengths{$id};
  next unless $length;
I think what this is doing is, checking if the $length record, which is linked to $id in the first file matches the $id in the second file? Eh...I think I am getting a bit lost :|

Comment: Oh and I wish there was a way to select 2 answers as I love both your and @raina77ow's answer! It feels real great to be able to learn new things. And as far as using a database, well sir, not too much of it is covered in the book, there are only 1-2 examples of creating a DBM file, and to be honest, I did not understand it that well :/ So ahem, things like SQLite, might initially appear a bit advanced for me.

Answer (score 1):

Too much questions for one question... But here we go anyway:

```
push @{$seen{$key}}, $item;
```

`%seen` is a hash (or associative array), so `$seen{$key}` recovers from `%seen` the value associated to that key `$key`. Then this value is treated as an array reference and transformed into an array by using `@{}` operator. Finally `$item` is added at the end of this array.

I don't understand what you mean by length... You mean the previous array length?

And to save this in a file, you just need to `print()` in your script and redirect to a file when executing the script, for example:

```
./my_perl_script.pl > my_output_file
```

Same goes for file input, you don't really need to `open()`, `close()` and such. This is more flexible and faster to code:

```
./my_perl_script.pl < my_input_file
```

This allows you to pipe this in a easier way and pass data from/to other scripts/processes. Of course both redirections can be used at the same time:

```
./my_perl_script.pl < my_input_file > my_output_file
```

Also you don't even need to save into a file (well it's always wise to have a copy of processed data anyway) and you can pipe directly the results to the other process, like

```
./my_perl_script.pl | my_other_script
```

This works on all OS I've used to far (Windows, Linux, OS X, BSD).

Comment: Wow m0skit0! Many thanks for taking the time to go through my problem and patiently write an answer to me. That explanation for push @{{$seen{$key}} was fabulous! Many thanks! This is a completely *new* data structure for me, at least it is not covered in the book I am referring to: Beginning Perl for Bioinformatics. I could understand the {$seen{$key} part, but treating it as an array refrence and transforming it into an array, wow! That was totally new!

Comment: By "length" I am referring to the length value associated with each id eg the length value of id 'NM_345' is '5008' in @array1

Comment: Those nifty lines to save output are so sleek! Of course, the output file is also saving the user prompts of "Enter file name" and "Enter second file name". Is this expected? The input file command works like a dream!

Comment: Ok, but your code is a bit of... mess, if you don't mind. For example, having @data and @data2 arrays is redundant and uses memory for nothing. Check raina77ow's answer, which presents a much more compact and effective code. About the strings you don't want in the output file, you can use STDOUT and STDERR to differentiate what you want in the output file. For example, using `print(STDERR "Hello\n");` you won't get this print() redirected to your file. You can redirect STDERR using 2> redirection operator if you want to, that is `./my_perl_script.pl 2> my_output_file`. Both can be used too.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** I leave [the link](http://codepad.org/a9QXEmdU) to the original answer's code to illustrate the concept of abstracting different subtasks (especially the processing one). But your problem can be solved much easier, if you're sure about what to expect in the input files:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $lengths_filename = 'Transcriptlength.fa';
my $counts_filename  = 'Quadcount.AllGtranscripts.fa';

my %sequence;   # it will be the basic data repository

local $/ = ''; 
# ...by this we ensure that files will be read by logical blocks instead of lines. 
# Might need some tweaking, if 'empty line' in your sample is not really empty.

# we start processing from 'counts' file, as only those records present in it
# should actually be in our output:
open my $cfh, '<', $counts_filename 
  or die $!, "\n";
while (<$cfh>) {
  # each logical block consists of two parts, divided by whitespace
  my ($name, $count) = split; 

  # here goes magic: we simultaneously create a new record in our repository...
  # ... and set its 'count' property to the value, extracted from the scanned fileblock
  $sequence{$name}{count} = $count;
}
close $cfh;

# now we go for lengths, approach is almost the same
open my $lfh, '<', $lengths_filename or die $!, "\n";
while (<$lfh>) {
  my ($name, $length) = split;

  # here we check that the sequence was in 'counts' file
  if (exists $sequence{$name}) { 
    $sequence{$name}{length} = $length;
  } 
}
close $lfh;

# and now the output block: it's mostly the same as in the original answer:
for my $name (sort keys %sequence) {
  print "$name, $sequence{$name}{count}, $sequence{$name}{length}", "\n";
}
```

Here's another [codepad](http://codepad.org/xmAJDdvo) to illustrate how it works. Don't mind strange `__DATA__` stuff, it's just for this specific version of program (using `__DATA__` section allows me to simulate reading from files, as I can't use external sources at codepad).

Comment: You did his homework for him does that mean you get the grade instead?

Comment: Well, I often help 'genetics' people with both detailed explanation and a bunch of code lines to illustrate it. I don't suppose that it's a homework, I think of it as a task needs to be solved by a person who does not know enough to do it - but _is_ willing to learn. That's why I give him not only some basic principles or links to documentation - but a real food for thought instead.

Comment: Yours was well written and didn't deserve my snide remark.  It's hard some posts to figure out how much to give away and I'm more the crusty old programmer than the patient teacher type;-)

Comment: @raina77ow: IMO building a hash for each record instead of an array complicates things unnecessarily. You have also made things even harder by assuming there are multiple lengths per sequence while there is nothing in the question to say so. My guess is that a sequence has only one length.

Comment: @Borodin I remember answering a very similar question in the Perl mailing list; in this question it all started from a similar assumption (that one element would suffice), but then it turned out that we'd talked about multiple values all the time. My code will work with both cases, as you see - even the modification given in P.S. is not really necessary.

Comment: @raina77ow : Wowiee!! What a detailed reply and explanation! Many many thanks sir! There is a lot of new information in your reply , for starters, the "map" function. It is not even mentioned in the book I am referring, "Beginning Perl for Bioinformatics". So, I have my task set for today. 1. Read about the new things in the code. 2. Figure out a way to get the data from the file into a hash, instead of array. Hmm.

Comment: Oh and I must mention all the sequence id numbers are unique in both the files. There is no repetitive data anywhere. 1st file has 40,000+ id names with their respective lengths. 2nd file has 20,000+id names with the G-quad numbers.

Comment: `map` is considered by some an advanced stuff, but frankly, I don't understand why. What's so advanced in the simple concept: `do something for each element of a collection`?

Comment: @raina77ow: `map` is not *do something for each element of a collection* - `foreach` does that. `map` is a *mapping* or function of a *list* that creates one list from another.

Comment: Thanks, have struggled to express it in terms of list comprehension. )

Comment: @raina77ow: ... which is precisely why it is often considered advanced. It isn't a very common concept in programming languages. I raised my comment because the way of thinking you described often results in people writing abominations like `map { print "$_\n" } @array`.

Comment: @Borodin Well, that struggle was definitely caused not by confusing `foreach` and `map/grep` purposes. ) English is not my first language.

Comment: As for list comprehension commonness: which more-o-less popular languages don't have such mechanisms? JavaScript won't count, as it can be easily extended with jQuery library. :P

Comment: @raina77ow First of all, big apologies for this late reply. I was feeling unwell since past 2 days. Okay, so wow! There is no way I could have come up with a code remotely resembling yours. There are so many new things in your code, making everything so elegant! For example, I did not know one could use a string ($cfh) as a filehandle. The use of "<" as input is also brand new to me. So is the use of "split", $! and of course, your master stroke of $sequence{$name}{count} = $count! I mean it's just fantastic! Brilliant!

Comment: @raina77ow In fact, I see that both you and Borodin have used a similar logic! Great minds think alike I say! :)

Comment: Now, I really don't know whose answer to select as both answers are simply brilliant to me! There is something new to learn in both the answers and all of it is really fascinating to me.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
 $data = join ('',@data); #Convert to string
@data2 = split('\n',$data); #Explode along newlines
```

Does not create your array like you think.  It just recreates the line sructure you started with.  I think you meant to split on "," commas. Use debugging tools.  At a minimum insert a print block like this

```
print join(":", @data2);
```

to see what is actually in your array.

Get each line working before you move on to the next one.  Then, if you can't figure out  why  a line isn't working you can post a question here.

As it is, it's hard for use to tell what you were trying to say in the code because the ideas are incomplete.